# Prestashop redirect ("/")

Tags: php, .htaccess, prestashop, redirect

Ive got Prestashop runing all good, but what trying to accomplish is redirection...

basicaly when you enter websitename + /category name it leads to category and its perfectly fine but when you enter that combinaiton without "/" at the end it leads to "404 page". SEO told me it matters for them....

How do i redirect "http://shop/phones" to "http://shop/phones/", any ideas? Thank you for your comments in advance.

Comment: who is SEO? have you access to the .htaccess file? if so, optimize your rule, if not so ask the admin to do this or write links in the way it is defined

Comment: SEO - search engine optimization

Comment: it was ironically (: with seo!

Comment: I tried many rule variations in .htaccess file before posting this question, could you be more specific if you ever faced this or simular problem

Comment: show us your .htaccess rule to solve your problem

Comment: .htaccess rule wont work here from what i understand because its not just a single category.... writing rules for every category thats going to be created is not an answer.

Comment: it has somthing to do with dispatcher.php, its included in .htaccess file and adds presta-specific rules

Comment: I don't think trailing slash any matter for search engine optimization

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go in:

> Preferences -> SEO & URLs

Then under "SCHEMA OF URLS" change this rule "Route to category":

```
{id}-{rewrite}
```

In this:

```
{id}-{rewrite}/
```

Save and test. I guess now you have the right redirect

Comment: But this way category URL without slash will redirect to 404?

Comment: If you give to PS the URL without slash the dispatcher will create the new url with slash, nothing else. No 404.

Answer (score 0):

Later, you don't forget redirect all urls without slash to all urls with slash with code in `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteRule ^([^.?]+[^.?/])$ $1/ [R=301,L]
```